# Linking array with Subclasses

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, collections, arraylist

my current program is a pupil library system, I have my array lists, menus and methods which all work. My problem is i need the arrays to be reading from the superclass LoanBook which takes in overrides from the Subclasses (Fiction and NonFiction).

As you can see from the AddBook method, it takes in details of the book and stores to an array list.

My Question :
I need to add the option Fiction or Non-Fiction but i need the arraylist take take property's from the Superclass and SubClasses. Can i get some help please.

Im happy to answer any questions you may have or provide more information.

Main Class

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static boolean run = true;
    static Formatter x;


    public static void main(String[]args){

        LoanBook myBook = new LoanBook();

        while (run){                    // this while statement allows the menu to come up again
            int answer = 0;
            boolean isNumber;
            do{                              // start of validation
                System.out.println("1.  Add book");
                System.out.println("2.  Display the books available for loan");
                System.out.println("3.  Display the books currently on loan");
                System.out.println("4.  Make a book loan");
                System.out.println("5.  Return book ");
                System.out.println("6   Write book details to file");
                if (keyboard.hasNextInt()){                       // I need to consider putting in a =>1 <=6
                    answer = keyboard.nextInt();
                    isNumber = true;
                }   else {
                    System.out.print(" You must enter a number from the menu to continue. \n");
                    isNumber = false;
                    keyboard.next(); // clears keyboard

                }
            }
            while (!(isNumber));
            switch (answer){

                case 1:
                    addBook();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewAll();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    booksOnLoan();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    loanBook();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    returnBook();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    writeToFile();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    static List<String>pupilName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String>issueDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String>bookTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String>bookAuthor = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List bookOnloan = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    public static void viewAll(){
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int x = 0; x < bookTitle.size();x++){
            int counter = x+1;
            System.out.println("BookID:" +counter + "\n " + bookTitle.get(x) + " - " + bookAuthor.get(x)+" " + bookOnloan.get(x));
        }
    }
    public static void booksOnLoan(){
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int x = 0; x < pupilName.size();x++){
            if (bookOnloan.contains(true)){
                int counter = x+1;
            System.out.println("BookID:" +counter + "\n "+"Pupil name: " + pupilName.get(x)
                    +"\n Book Title: "+ bookTitle.get(x) + " by " + bookAuthor.get(x)+" " + bookOnloan.get(x)+ "\n Issued: "+ issueDate.get(x)) ;
            }
        }
    }



    public static void addBook(){

        System.out.println("Please enter the book title: ");
        String newTitle = keyboard.next();
        bookTitle.add(newTitle);
        System.out.println("Please enter the book author");
        String newAuthor = keyboard.next();
        bookAuthor.add(newAuthor);
        bookOnloan.add(false);
        System.out.println("\n Your book: "+ bookTitle.get(bookTitle.size()-1)+ " has been added to the library" + "\n");
    }

    public static void loanBook(){
        viewAll();
        System.out.println("Please choose the BookID you would like to issue: ");
        int issue = keyboard.nextInt()-1;
        if (issue > 10){
            System.out.println("Invalid book selection");
        }
        else {
            bookOnloan.set(issue,true);
            System.out.println("Please enter pupil name: ");
            String newPupil = keyboard.next();
            pupilName.add(newPupil);
            System.out.println("Please enter date of issue: ");
            String newIssue = keyboard.next();
            issueDate.add(newIssue);
        }
    }
    public static void returnBook(){
       // booksOnLoan();
        System.out.println("Please choose the BookID you would like to return: ");
        int issue = keyboard.nextInt()-1;
        if (issue > 10){
            System.out.println("Invalid book selection");
        }
        else {
            bookOnloan.set(issue,false);
```

Next is my Superclass

```
public class LoanBook {


    private int bookID;
    private String title,author,name,date;
    boolean onLoan;
    private static int count = 0;
    static List<String> bookTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String>bookAuthor = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> pupilName = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String>issueDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List bookOnloan = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public LoanBook(String title,String author){  //constructor
        this.bookID = count;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        bookOnloan.add(false);
        count++;
    }



    public void setTitle(String title){
        bookTitle.set(1,title);

    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return  bookTitle.toString();
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author){
        bookTitle.set(1,author);

    }
    public String getAuthor(){
        return  bookAuthor.toString();
    }
    public String getName(){
        return pupilName.toString();
    }
    public void setName(String name){
           pupilName.set(1,name);
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return issueDate.toString();
    }
    public void setDate(String date){
        issueDate.set(1,date);
    }

    public Boolean getOnloan(){
        return bookOnloan.add(false);
    }
    public void setOnLoan(Boolean onLoan){
        bookOnloan.add(false);

    }

}
```

Next my subclasses

```
public class Fiction extends LoanBook {

    private String type;

    public Fiction(){

    }


    public Fiction(String title,String author, String type){
        super(title,author);                    //calls constructor of the superclass
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        type = "Fiction";
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + " The book type is: " + getType()+"\n";
    }
}
```

and the other subclasss

```
public class NonFiction extends LoanBook {

    private String type;

    public NonFiction(){

    }


    public NonFiction(String title,String author, String type){
        super(title,author);                    //calls constructor of the superclass
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        type = "Fiction";
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + " The book type is: " + getType()+"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code to understand in a minute, but the static lists in `LoanBook` look very wrong. 5 dollars that they are causing your problems.

Comment: A good suggestion would be to change your design of LoanBook class.

Comment: Could somebody correct my LoanBook class so i can work from there?

Comment: `"Could somebody correct my LoanBook class so i can work from there?"` -- **NO**, this is not a "fix my code for me site". I've given you suggestions on what you should do, and I suggest you heed them. If you get stuck implementing them, then ask questions, but please never ask anyone to do your work for you again. That's not how you learn, and that's not how this, or any reputable site works.

Comment: Your suggestions ask me to restart my whole code, ive been working on this for ages and its due in tomorrow. I see form your profile your self taught so how can i agree to your answer?

Comment: Can anybody tell me if i can link and array with Loanbook?

Comment: `"Your suggestions ask me to restart my whole code, ive been working on this for ages and its due in tomorrow."` -- your due-date is not our responsibility and does not have relevance to the over all problem, and posting it will not change the help you receive. Regardless of how long you've been working on it, it's terribly broken -- restart it. `"I see form your profile your self taught so how can i agree to your answer?"`  -- this makes no sense at all.

Comment: `"Can anybody tell me if i can link and array with Loanbook?"` this is not a clear question. Please restate. Please read my suggestions as they explain what you must do -- get rid of your LoanBook class as it will not work in any situation.

Comment: LoanBook is required, Fiction and Non are also required to extend loan book, Main must pass in details to LoanBook. i have it coded in a different way without arrays but its broken also, just as bad.

Comment: The bottom line is that you **must** separate out your concept of Book and BookLibrary or collection into at least two classes. I'm not sure which one should be named LoanBook since you've not posted your requirement. As per the first point in my answer, this is the primary problem with your code. If you need more help, give more details, ask more questions, and again, don't beg for code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im going to restart the code from scratch, it will be a long night but ill be asking several questions here, i suppose it will help peoples rep and improve my knowledge. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole program structure is broken from your over-use of static fields to your mis-use of inheritance, to your combining the concepts of a Book and a Book collection all in one class.

Suggestions:

- Don't mix your Book class with your Book collection. This looks to be the primary problem with your code.
- Start with just a Book class. It should contain no lists at all.
- You can have FictionBook and NonFictionBook extend Book if so desired.
- Or you could simply give Book a boolean field, fiction, and set it to true or false depending on the needs.
- Create a LoanBook class that holds  List of Books.
- Don't use inheritance unless a true "is-a" relationship exists. Your code does not satisfy this mainly due to your first problem, your mixing your Book class together with your Book Library code, which forces your Fiction book and your non-Fiction book to inherit library code which is not only not needed, but really detrimental.
- Avoid use of static anythings, unless they are there for a specific static purpose.
- You will likely be best served by trashing your current code and re-starting over.